# 500 Internal Server Error on Subversion Commit / USVN / Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, apache, svn, debian, raspberry-pi

I am using [User-Friendly SVN](http://www.usvn.info/) on my Raspberry Pi. The Pi is running with Debian Wheezy.

Creating repositories is working and I can checkout and update the repository without any problem. But when I create a file, add it to the repository and try to commit, I get this message:

```
svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175002: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Error) in response to POST request for '/usvn/svn/test/!svn/me'
svn: E175002: Your commit message was left in a temporary file:
svn: E175002:    '/svntest/test/svn-commit.tmp'
```

There is nothing in the error.log, but in the access.log I can find this:

```
192.168.10.34 - - [22/Sep/2013:10:23:14 +0200] "OPTIONS /usvn/svn/test/trunk HTTP/1.1" 401 653 "-" "SVN/1.7.5 neon/0.29.6"
192.168.10.34 - admin [22/Sep/2013:10:23:17 +0200] "OPTIONS /usvn/svn/test/trunk HTTP/1.1" 200 1347 "-" "SVN/1.7.5 neon/0.29.6"
192.168.10.34 - admin [22/Sep/2013:10:23:18 +0200] "POST /usvn/svn/test/!svn/me HTTP/1.1" 500 548 "-" "SVN/1.7.5 neon/0.29.6"
```

The SVN-Path has read and write access for www-data.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same problem and wasn't satisfied with py3r3str's fix. I figured out if I changed the usvn/public/.htaccess file I could exclude the repos from the rewrite rule and this fixed the problem for me:

```
<Files *.ini>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>

php_flag short_open_tag on
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond
RewriteBase "//usvn/"
RewriteRule ^svn/ - [L,NC] #this is the rule I added to fix the 500 errors
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue.
I've notice that /svn/test/!svn/me request is catch by usvn web application instead of svn server.
My solution of this problem is to change subdomain of svn server that works for me.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Are you on 64 bit OS ?

I'm facing the same error with win7 64Bit and not with win7 32bit.

Try remove tortoise 64 and install tortoise SVN for 32 bit OS :

http://www.oldversion.fr/windows/tortoisesvn-1-6-10

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is running on an ARM Debian (Linux).
I am not using Tortoise...

You can not compare apples and oranges

Answer (score 0):

I could not avoid the error in the description method of htaccess of allen. 
So I fix this.

```
<Files *.ini>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>

php_flag short_open_tag on
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /usvn

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule !^svn\/ index.php  [L]
</IfModule>
```